# How to launch an Activity from a TextView?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, textview

I have a TextView and i want to tap on it to launch an other activity. Is that posible?
I tried that (wrong) code, because i really did not find a solution:

```
TextView tv= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.souple);
        tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener{
            public void onClick(View v){
                  Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
                  startActivity(intent);
            }
     });
```

ERROR: `Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)`

So any idea please?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go, i've found finally a solution:

```
public class ServicesPlus extends Activity  {
    TextView t ;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.servicesplus);

        t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.souple);

        t.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                  public void onClick(View v) {
                      Toast.makeText(ServicesPlus.this, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }   });

}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to refer to your current activity through `this` in Intent constructor. You should change it to `YourActivity.this` to avoid ambiguation.

Comment: The problem is in `setOnClickListener` : `Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)`

Comment: Oh, you also miss parentheses from this declaration. It should be `new View.OnClickListener() { ... }` instead of `new View.OnClickListener { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Inside the OnClickListener 'this' is the listener, not the Activity. So, you'll want to create a Context variable in the Activity class and set it to this, then use it in your listener.

```
Context c = this;

OnClickListener....{

   new Intent(c, OtherActivity.class)
}
```

Comment: Sorry but the problem is not in `Intent`, but in `tv.setOnClickListener` :\

Answer (score 0):

You missed the paranthesis after `View.OnClickListener`